# Why does the same code from Arduino IDE give different outputs on different laptops?

Tags: arduino, embedded, system, i2c, keypad

I was trying to interface a Keypad (4*4 membrane type) via I2C (PCF8574AT) converter module with Arduino Uno.

**A1, A2, A3 pin grounded. So the I2CADDR is 0x38.**

Compiled and ran this code on my Lenovo T440s and it showed:

```
Press anykey:
B
```

And then no matter how many times I press on the keypad nothing will come up on the serial monitor. On the other hand when I run the same on code on T430s it runs successfully.

Showing

```
Press any key:
and then on pressing key it was showing 1,2 ,3 etc
```

Arduino version used 1.8.2 on both.
Exact same code and library still different output.
Can anyone explain why?

Here is my code:

```
/* @file CustomKeypad.pde
  || @version 1.0
  || @author Alexander Brevig
  || @contact alexanderbrevig@gmail.com
  ||
  || @description
  || | Demonstrates changing the keypad size and key values.
  || #
    Use with I2C i/o G. D. (Joe) Young Feb 28/12
*/

#include <Keypad_I2C.h>
#include <Keypad.h> // GDY120705
#include <Wire.h>

#define I2CADDR 0x38
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the symbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {0, 1, 2, 3}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {4, 5, 6, 7}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad_I2C customKeypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS, I2CADDR);

void setup() {
  // Wire.begin();
  customKeypad.begin(); // GDY120705
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Press Keys");
}

void loop() {
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  if (customKey != NO_KEY) {
    Serial.println(customKey);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Yes I added my code - @Piglet

Comment: @TomServo is it alright now?

Answer (score 0):

Verify your hardware at first.
I tried this issue when I was developing a project with 8*8 key matrix long time ago. It might be somewhere ports change too fast and without discharge thus makes false trigger.

Comment: welcome to SO. This post would probably be better suited as a comment, because it is more of a suggesting than an answer. When answering a question, you should be confident that your answer can solve OP's problem.

Comment: Well, Hardware is just fine, I think. Its working smoothly on T430 right? So if there were any flaws then it shouldn't run. I guess? I am too noob here. So, sorry if i am saying anything wrong.

Comment: Is it better to have a trouble-shoot step by step?
Since the connection now is:
4*4keypad <=> I2C chip <=> computer

Let's find out which part is with something wrong...,
for example, get a DMM and check if 4*4 keypad works correctly in logic,
or re-plug the USB port, or check if Vdd is at the normal operating voltage (3.3V or 5V?) ... Hope these methods could help you indeed.

Comment: Got it. But the problem is not that. You see I checked the code in my serial monitor its not working, That moment I took another laptop from my friend and tried on his and it works. If there were hardware problem it shouldn't run on his laptop just right after one minute of trying on mine. Don't you think?

Comment: But as u said i used Saleae logic analyzer to check. And re-checked the connection but same result.